# Indexing a Varchar with MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, varchar

I have a table `foo` like this:

```
id | column1
1  | normalized_string_format1
2  | normalized_string_format1
3  | normalized_string_format2
4  | normalized_string_format3
```

The queries on the table are always:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE column1 = 'some_string'
```

and

```
INSERT INTO foo (column1) VALUES ('some_string')
```

Note that two first rows in the example above has `normalized_string_format1` so column1 is not unique. Should I do create some index in column1 in order to increase the performance? in such case, which one index should I choise?

Comment: Yes, you should probably index `column1` if you're doing `where column1` queries. Check the output of `EXPLAIN <your query>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table `foo` is non-trivial, then adding an index on column1 will likely benefit performance.

You could create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_IX1 ON foo (column1)
```

The INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements will do more work, to maintain the index entries.

But the SELECT statement with an equality predicate on column1 will be able to use an index range scan operation, which means that it can avoid inspect every flipping row in the table.